# Tomcat won't undeploy ROOT.war

Tags: rest, tomcat, undeploy

I deployed using the REST API of Tomcat Manager (*/manager/text*) my application. The war is ROOT.war. When I try to undeploy it using */manager/text/undeploy?path=/* Tomcat fails to undeploy with response:

```
FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
```

But if I try to use the Tomcat Manager GUI it can undeploy the war
Does someone know how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the ROOT deployed directory manually?

The war's are simply exploded to directories under the webapps folder.